# Changing no of rows displayed, depending on value selected in a select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select box having options 25,30,40 etc. I want to change the number of rows displayed in the table based on value selected i.e when a user selects 25 he should see only 25 rows and if he selects 40 he should see 40 rows

Comment: What you tries so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and refine your question accordingly.